# Getting max value if a counted cookieID while showing the cookieID and showing it belongs to bakkerID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the weird title I have hard time putting the problem into words
but this is the problem I'm facing. so this is my table

**bakkery**:

```
BakkerID | CookieID
---------+----------
  6534       1009
  6534       1009
  6534         50 
  1327          5
  1327          8
  1327          8
```

and I'm trying to get this result

```
bakkerID cookieID total
-------------------------
6534      1009      2
1327         8      2
```

So I want to count the `cookieID` and get the max value while also holding on to the `cookieID` and the `bakkerID`. But I only want the max result.

I tried this via a subquery like this

```
SELECT 
    MAX(cookie_count) AS total, 
    bakkerId, cookieID
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(cookieID) AS cookie_count, 
         bakkerId, cookieID 
     FROM 
         bakkery
     GROUP BY  
         bakkerID, cookieID) AS cookie_counter_table
GROUP BY  
    bakkerID, cookieID
```

but the result will be

```
bakkerID cookieID total
-----------------------
6534       1009     2
6534         50     1 
1327          8     2
1327          5     1
```

Now this does not work because of the group by but I also can't leave it out else I will get a error that its no in a group by. I tried using where or having but I this can result in duplicated `bakkerID` which I don't want. So my question is: how do I stop the not max result from showing up or am I doing this all wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT bakkerId, MAX(cookie_count),
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN cookieID END) as max_cookieId
FROM (SELECT bakkerId, cookieID, COUNT(*) AS cookie_count,  
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bakkerId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM bakkery
      GROUP BY  bakkerID, cookieID
     ) bc
GROUP BY bakkerId;
```

Comment: Thanks this was the answer to my problem. tho no clue how it works but that now for me to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
SELECT  BakkerID,
        MaxCookieID CookieID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MaxCookieID = CookieID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) total
FROM (  SELECT  *, 
                MAX(CookieID) OVER(PARTITION BY BakkerID) MaxCookieID
        FROM dbo.bakkery) b
GROUP BY BakkerID,
         MaxCookieID;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
select BakkerID,CookieID,total from 
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (partition by bakkerid,cookieId) AS total,
                                ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by bakkerid order by cookieId desc) as rn, 
                                bakkerId,
                                cookieID 
                                FROM bakkery
                                                ) x
where x.rn=1
order by BakkerID desc
```